# What is the name of this FASTON-like crimp terminal with a spring?

Tags: switches, wire-terminals, crimp

I use 2.2mm FASTON-like connectors (top of first image) to connect to the male terminals of the illuminated switch on the left, but they are a pain to connect and sometimes even damage the male terminal.

I found a terminal that is way easier to attach (bottom of first image with blue wire attached) which has a small sheet inside it that acts like a spring and a dent on top to fix the male terminal in place, but I cannot find the name of that terminal. What is the name?

Follow-up: Is there a recommended female terminal type for the male terminals?

[image: Male and female terminals, FASTON and ???]

The bottom terminal was harvested from a socket that is sold with the buttons (see image 2).
But there don't seem to be any sockets for the 12 mm illuminated switches, only the quick connects (also see image 2).

[image: sockets and terminals]

Comment: Are you sure that those are not solder tags?

Comment: @AndrewMorton At least it is not advertised as solder tags. (I updated the question with additional info)

Comment: @DavideAndrea No, not really. The question also contains a female terminal with a spring-mechanism, but its name is not discussed.

Answer (score 1):

The connectors that you mention are known as Lucar connectors.

Here's a view of an automotive oil pressure switch with a male Lucar connector.

[image]

*Image credit:* [AliExpress](https://vi.aliexpress.com/item/1005003036658379.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2vnm)

The following is a magnified view of the mating female connector.

[image]

*Image credit:* [Ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/224944309644)

The bump in this connector is seated in the hole in the male to secure the electrical connection.

Oblong slits, in the male terminals of the component in your photograph, indicate that they are wire solder tags and not Lucar connectors.

Comment: That is the type of the terminal that I currently use. The terminal in question (with the blue wire attached) is not of that type.

Answer (score 1):

> to the male terminals

Those are solder eyelets. They are not intended for removable female connectors. They are only intended for soldering a wire to it. That's the only reliable way to connect to them. Sure, you can jury rig a female terminal to them, but it will soon slip off.

Comment: At least the seller advertises sockets alongside the button that contain the terminal crimp on the bottom of the first image.

And they actually fit pretty good. The advantage over the quick-connects is that they are easier to attach while at the same time need a lot of force to detach.

Comment: That is a "switch", not a "button". Specifically, it's a momentary push-button switch. It may be that your switch has short tabs only suitable for soldering. The switch sockets you show may be for switches with longer terminals.

Comment: There are both momentary and latching variants. If it shall be soldered, that is probably pretty hard to do without damaging the plastic.

Anyway, there is a spring on that female terminal in question. It is obviously not a quick disconnect. But what it is remains a mystery.

Comment: "But what it is remains a mystery." It's not a mystery to us: it's a solder eyelet.

Comment: The question is about the _female_ terminal that contains a spring (with the blue wire attached). Not the male terminal, not the FASTON-like terminal.

Comment: You are correct. I apologize. Instead of answering the proximate question you asked, I tried to solve the ultimate problem you face. I now understand that you prefer to receive an answer to the your perceived solution rather than to receive a suggestion for an effective solution. When you asked "Is there a recommended female terminal type for the male terminals?" I assumed you were asking for a solution to your problem. Forgive me for having misread your wish. I will now proceed and answer the question you asked, not the one I think would solve your problem. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

"terminal was harvested from a socket"

This probably means there is no any special *standard* name separate from the socket. It is simply a part of the whole unit, most likely manufactured specifically for these sockets.

Now, whether you can use any standard terminal for the same purpose is entirely different question.

Comment: True. Fore some reason the sockets only exist for the 16mm and 19mm diameter switches. For 12mm, there are none. But it is hard to imagine that there is no appropriate female part. The male counterpart does not look esoteric at all.

Answer (score 0):

> I found a terminal that is way easier to attach (bottom of first image with blue wire attached) which has a small sheet inside it that acts like a spring and a dent on top to fix the male terminal in place, but I cannot find the name of that terminal. What is the name?

TE part number 60577-1 is a quick-connect female disconnect with a dimple that snaps in the hole in a quick-connect tab.

TE part number 175411-1 is a quick-connect female disconnect with a latch and a dimple that snaps in the hole in a quick-connect tab. To remove it, you must lift the latch.

TE part number 63391-2 is a quick-connect female disconnect with a spring leaf in the back that squeezes a 2.2 mm quick-connect tab.

Again, sorry for not answering your direct question before. I hope you feel that this time I did answer your direct question.